# org.hibernate.MappingException: component property not found: id

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa

```
@Table
@Entity
@Data
public class GaunamasSiunciamas {

  @AttributeOverride(name = "siuntosNumeris", column = @Column(columnDefinition = "siuntos_numeris"))
  @EmbeddedId
  private Siuntinys siuntinys;
  @AttributeOverride(name = "dezutesNumeris", column = @Column(columnDefinition = "dezutes_numeris"))
  @Embedded
  private Skyrelis skyrelis;
  @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(columnDefinition = "kurjeris_id"))
  @Embedded
  private Kurjeris kurjeris;
  @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(columnDefinition = "siuntejas_id"))
  @Embedded
  private Siuntejas siuntejas;
  @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(columnDefinition = "gavejas_id"))
  @Embedded
  private Gavejas gavejas;
  private char siunciamaGaunama;
  private java.sql.Timestamp ideta;
  private java.sql.Timestamp paimta;
  private int kurjerioPin;
  private int gavejoPin;
}
```

Links to

```
@Entity
@Data
@Embeddable
public class Siuntinys implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "siuntos_numeris")
  private @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  int siuntosNumeris;
  @ManyToOne
  private Kurjeris kurjeris;
  @ManyToOne
  private Sandelys sandelys;
  @OneToOne
  private Siuntejas siuntejas;
  @ManyToOne
  private PastoDarbuotojas darbuotojas;
  @ManyToOne
  private Gavejas gavejas;
  @ManyToOne
  private Pristatymas pristaymoNumeris;
  @ManyToOne
  private PervezimasIsSandelioISandeli pervezimas;
  private double siuntosSvoris;
  private String siuntosBusena;
  private char pristatymoTipas;
  private char siuntimoTipas;
}
```

and I get an error:

> Invocation of init method failed;
> nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException:
> component property not found: siuntosNumeris

Any ideas? I haven't found anything similar in the past 2 days

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue:

```
 @AttributeOverride(name = "id" ...
```

The attribute `name` refers to the property of the class you want to override, but there is no property `id` anywhere. From what I see, you want to use `@Column` instead.

Anyway, the whole mapping doesn't seem correct.

`Siuntinys` cannot be an [embeddable](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#embeddables) and an entity.
From your mapping it seems it should be an entity and shouldn't be used as an id.

The same is true for all the other associations that you are mapping in one class as `@Embeddable` and in the other using `@ManyToOne`.

I would suggest to read the Hibernate ORM documentation about [associations](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations) and [identifiers](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers).